# Differential equation of a RRC circuit as Voltage output/voltage input?

Tags: passive-networks, formula-derivation

So in this presentation i have got, there is a RRC circuit, and they get this differential equation, but there is no procedure explained how they have got it. This is basicially a series RRC circuit because current I3 is zero, so it is the same current. Later when we would laplace transform final differential equation we would get transfer function Vo/Vi.

In images input voltage(Vi) is Eu, and output voltage(Vo) is Ui. In Final differential equation i think y should be Vo and u should be Vi.

So final when we laplace differential equation we should get the transfer function in the image where K and T would be equal to RC or something similiar.
Like in this example
[image: Example]

My question is how to get the final differential equation with Vo and Vi like this so i can get Vo/Vi, i searched the internet and couldn't find anything. English is not my first language so i couldn't express my self better.

RRC circuit

[image: RRC circuit]

Differential equations

[image: Differential equations]

Final differential equation

[image: Final differential equation]

Transfer function

[image: Transfer function]

Answer (score 1):

You're right to be lost with this one because it looks like the presentation is giving an example in the time domain and then ending with a generic format in the frequency domain (also weird that the schematic takes the time to define 3 separate current paths but instead just uses "i").

Using an s-domain table you can see that the final transfer function is a convolution between a step input and an exponential which makes sense because any voltage applied at the circuit input will immediately cause the output to rise to the R1/(R1+R2) voltage point and then charge the capacitor to the full voltage source level (exponential).

If you want to find the transfer function yourself (Vout/Vin aka G(s)), I'd solve the voltage divider equation in the frequency domain where "C" becomes "1/(sC)" (voltage drop across "R" is not frequency dependent so it stays as "R"). If you calculate the output voltage using the frequency domain equivalents, you should be able to distill the equation to the same format as their transfer function "template" and get values for "K" and "T."

The analysis would look similar to this but with the added complexity of R1 in series with 1/(sC) in the numerator and denominator:
http://www.analogzoo.com/2015/12/deriving-the-rc-filter-transfer-function/